# PHP Array toggle between two strings

Tags: php

I have an array with two values `$arr = ['up', 'down'];`. If someone casts an up vote (`$vote = 'up';`) the up field should be increased by one and the down field should be decreased by one in the database.

I could work with an if else condition:

```php
if ($vote === 'up') {
  $voteModel['up'] = $voteModel['up'] + 1;
  $voteModel['down'] = $voteModel['down'] - 1;
} else {
  $voteModel['up'] = $voteModel['up'] - 1;
  $voteModel['down'] = $voteModel['down'] + 1;
}
```

But I'm wondering if this can be made shorter. I was thinking of an `arr = ['up' => 'down'];` but unfortunately I'm not getting anywhere with that right now. Do you have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @NigelRen My fault 8-) I update. Thank you for good hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
$arg = $vote === 'up' ? [1,-1] : [-1,1];
$voteModel['up'] += $arg[0];
$voteModel['down'] += $arg[1];
```

Solution 2:

```
$voteModel['up'] += ($vote === 'up' ? 1 : -1);
$voteModel['down'] += ($vote !== 'up' ? 1 : -1);
```

Solution 3 (if 'up' is index 1 and 'down' is index 0 in `$voteModel`):

```
$voteModel[$vote==='up']++;
$voteModel[$vote==='down']--;
```

Solution 3b (if we want to keep the assoc keys):

```
$arr = ['down','up'];
$voteModel[$arr[$vote==='up']]++;
$voteModel[$arr[$vote==='down']]--;
```

Comment: Great FooBar! Many good answer but i think yours i like very much. It is super short :-)

Comment: @MaxPattern You asked for shorter once :-)

Comment: Yes that was my intension  Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Although you've asked for shorter, sometimes I think clarity is better. Most of the other answers include additional arrays or ternaries, which are totally fine and 100% valid, but I think the intention of the code isn't as obvious then. For me, I'd keep the `if` and just use `++` and `--` for increment and decrement. I think the "business rules" are very obvious and the code reads cleanly.

Once again, not exactly what you asked for, just my two cents.

```php
if ('up' === $vote) {
    $voteModel['up']++;
    $voteModel['down']--;
} else {
    $voteModel['up']--;
    $voteModel['down']++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris and for your good Answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by using some reference data. Use `$vote` value to find an entry in the $voteVals array telling it what values to increase and decrease by in each case. Then simply loop through the vote model, and action each entry by updating by the amount specified in the reference data. Matching is done simply using the "up" and "down" string values:

```
$voteVals = ["up" => ["up" => 1, "down" => -1], "down" => ["up" => -1, "down" => 1]];
$voteModel = ["up" => 0, "down" => 0];
$vote = "up";

$voteActionVals = $voteVals[$vote];

foreach ($voteActionVals as $key => $val)
    $voteModel[$key] += $val;

var_dump($voteModel);
```

Output:

> array(2) {
> ["up"]=>
> int(1)
> ["down"]=>
> int(-1)
> }

As you can see, this has incremented the "up" entry by 1 and decremented the "down" value by 1.

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/9oFHH

Comment: Thanks! Yours and @SlavaRoznev answer are very nice! Merci :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function vote($model, $vote) {
    $up = $vote === 'up' ? 1 : -1;
    $model['up'] +=  $up;
    $model['down'] -= $up;
    return $model;
}

$voteModel = [
        'up' => 5,
        'down' =>5
];


print_r(vote($voteModel, 'up'));

print_r(vote($voteModel, 'down'));
```

https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/77d709373d4e930e0e0113c11984e0b8/

One more:

```
function vote($model, $vote) {
    foreach($model as $key=>$val){
        $model[$key] = $val + ($vote === $key ? 1 : -1);
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: *But I'm wondering if this can be made shorter*?!

Answer (score -1):

The scoring system has two general methods.

1- Showing the number of positive votes and showing negative votes. Positive votes do not cancel out negative votes and negative votes do not cancel out positive votes. Like YouTube

2- Display the total number of votes as if you have a column of votes in the database. A positive score adds one to it and a negative score subtracts one from it.

So, for you who use the first mode, it is not necessary to add it to the scoring system in the case of a positive one and subtract one from it in the case of a negative score.

you can use this code

```php
$voteModel['up'] += $vote === 'up' ? 1 : -1;
$voteModel['down'] += $vote !== 'up' ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: is simple. just get value of ```$voteModel``` by ```$vote```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't implement one of the stated requirements. Read the question again, and also compare the functionality of your code to the functionality of the other answers.

Comment: wiche one of requirements?

Comment: Read the question again. Hint: _"If someone casts an up vote ($vote = 'up';) the up field should be increased by one **and** the down field should be decreased by one in the database."_ (my bold). Your code doesn't do that - demo: https://3v4l.org/WakJv

Comment: please read the edited answer

Comment: Your edit makes assumptions about the OP's requirement which are contrary to the question's contents. They actually stated their requirement very clearly in the question, from a technical point of view. Yes it may not be a standard way of doing such a scoring system, and we can certainly suggest that they change it - but that would be done via the comments, to question the overall logic. There's no real need to base an answer on that when they've very clearly stated what they are aiming for, unless the question is subsequently changed.

Comment: Also your code now makes less sense that it did before...it doesn't implement the stated requirement, _or_ either of the versions in your description - demo: https://3v4l.org/mtg0A . You should really test your code before posting it.

Comment: And now it's just a repeat of Solution 2 in Foobar's already-accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876440/5947043), which was posted before your edit

Comment: Also it seems a bit contradictory to say "don't do this" but then post code which does it anyway (especially without actually pointing that out...in fact the wording implies that the code would do what you said in point 1, but it doesn't). The answer is a bit incoherent now, IMHO, and it's not really necessary - if I was you, I'd just delete it.